# Is it safe to append id values to html form elements for quicker access or what is the best practise?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, servlets, jsp-tags

For example i have an `<option>` tag

```
<select>
<option id="123">user1</option>
<option id="124">user2</option>
<option id="125">user3</option>
<select>
```

which has text as username and userid from database as values,
and the corresponding database is:

```
user table(userid is primary key here)
userid username
123     user1
124     user2
125     user3

user details table(userid is foreign key here)
userid  amount
123     100
124     200
125     400
```

For example based on option selected i go the user details table and get the amount.Now there are two approaches

1. Get the name of user from selected option,send it to a servlet fetch the corresponding `userid` and then amount
2. Directly send the `userid` to servlet by saving `userid` in value attribute of select tag 
   and fetch the amount

I find second method quicker and reasonable but is it safe or else what is the best approach.How do people running websites achieve this quicker usually ?

Comment: You ***should*** pass userid, thats what user ids are for

Comment: Is the user changing their own info?: sessions. Is the user changing someone elses?: make it a hidden input in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use JOIN:

```
SELECT `user_detail`.`amount`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `user_details`
ON `user`.`userid` = `user_details`.`userid`
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would want to reduce the amount of server operations as much as possible. The step 1 would require 2 lookups in the database while it only takes 1 lookup using the ID in the second step. Thus, it's recommended that you would use the IDs of the objects when communicating with the server. After all, ID means IDentifier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sending IDs is fine but as castis pointed out, you should ensure the select is refreshed if users IDs can change.

DB access is expensive especially if they're on different servers and you have to open connections each time. You should be using connection pooling anyway. What you can do is bring in the user detail table and cache it in memory for your servlet to access. This all depends how big that user detail table is, how often it changes, and server resources.  It'll be a whole lot faster than hitting the DB.